# Angular $http not invoking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I'm new to angular js. In my current project I wrote following code for authorization in a directive. For some reason $http post call is not invoking when I call validateUser function.

```
authorizationModule.factory('authorizationFactory',['$http','$q',function(http,q) {
    return {
        validateUser : function(input){
            var deferred = q.defer();
            http({              
                url: '/OutageRequest/AuthenticationServlet',
                method: 'post',
                data: {'authCode': input }
                }).
                  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      console.log(data);
                      deferred.resolve(data);
                  }).
                  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      console.log(status);
                      deferred.reject();
                  });
             return deferred.promise;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$scope.$apply` did the trick.